# Concatenate several rows into one row by column value, and split resulting dataframe into several dataframes based on number of concatinated rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe where several rows share the particular column value. For those rows, I want to concatenate these rows into a single row. And single there are variations for the number of rows with the shared column value, I want to split these dataframes into their own separate dataframe, so a unique dataframe for a particular number of shared rows.

Here is an example of what I want.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['tom', 2], ['ni2ck', 2], ['j3uli', 4] , ['nic4k', 4], ['jul5i', 4] , ['nic6k', 7], ['ju7li', 7] , ['nic8k', 7], ['ju9li', 7] , ['nic1k', 8], ['car', 8]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age']) 
df
```

The code above generates what the original dataframe would look like

The result would be

```
Name    Age
0   tom 2
1   ni2ck   2
2   j3uli   4
3   nic4k   4
4   jul5i   4
5   nic6k   7
6   ju7li   7
7   nic8k   7
8   ju9li   7
9   nic1k   8
10  car 8
```

I want to put all rows the share the same Age column into one row, and then separate the dataframe based on the number of columns that are generated for each shared row. So the result would look like this

first result dataframe, which has two rows, since there are two lines that share the same number of columns.

```
Name    Name    Age
0   tom ni2ck   2
1   nic1k   car 8
```

second result dataframe

```
Name    Name    Name    Age
0   j3uli   nic4k   jul5i   4
```

third result dataframe

```
    Name    Name    Name    Name    Age
0   nic6k   ju7li   nic8k   ju9li   7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way

```
df['New']=df.groupby('Age').cumcount()
s=df.pivot(index='Age',columns='New',values='Name')
l=[ y.dropna(1) for _ , y in s.groupby(s.isnull().sum(1))]
l[0]
New      0      1      2      3
Age                            
7    nic6k  ju7li  nic8k  ju9li
l[1]
New      0      1      2
Age                     
4    j3uli  nic4k  jul5i
l[2]
New      0      1
Age              
2      tom  ni2ck
8    nic1k    car
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for age, df_ in df.groupby('Age'):
    d[len(df_.T.columns)].append(df_.reset_index(drop=True).T.loc[['Name']].assign(Age=age))

d = {k: pd.concat(v, ignore_index=True ) for k,v in d.items()}
```

Then, access the dataframes by the number of names they have. For example,

```
>>> d[2]
```

```
       0      1  Age
0    tom  ni2ck    2
1  nic1k    car    8
```

---

```
>>> d[3]
```

```
       0      1      2  Age
0  j3uli  nic4k  jul5i    4
```